# How do I link a specific field of my two django models with each other?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two different models in my django database. One for my companies and for my contacts as follows:

companies.models:

```
from django.db import models

class CompaniesDetailView(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Enter Company Name", max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField("Enter Email")
    phone_number = models.CharField("Enter Phone Number", max_length=12)
    contact_name = models.CharField("Enter Contact Persons Name", max_length=50)

    company_image = models.ImageField(default='default-avatar.png', upload_to='companies/', null=True, blank=True)


def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % (self.name)
```

contacts.models:

```
from django.db import models
from apps.companies.models import CompaniesDetailView

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(CompaniesDetailView, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField("Enter Email")
    phone_number = models.CharField("Enter Phone Number", max_length=12)
    company_name = models.CharField("Enter Company Name", max_length=50)

    contact_image = models.ImageField(default='default-avatar.png', upload_to='contact/', null=True, blank=True)


def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % (self.name)
```

Now I want to link the two models such that when I create a company through Django an additional contact will be created from the contact_name of CompaniesDetailView. Currently if I try to create a contact it is taking the name of the companies.

I know the solution is simple but I can't seem to grasp it.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Django signals? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/

Answer (score 0):

Your CompaniesDetailView should be called Company, because it is a model and not a view. What I would suggest is to override the save method of your Company model.

```
class CompaniesDetailView(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Enter Company Name", max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField("Enter Email")
    phone_number = models.CharField("Enter Phone Number", max_length=12)
    contact_name = models.CharField("Enter Contact Persons Name", max_length=50)

    company_image = models.ImageField(default='default-avatar.png', upload_to='companies/', null=True, blank=True)

    def save(*args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        # create new contact
        c = Contact(name=self, ...)
        c.save()
```

The advantage of overriding the save method is that you have more control.

Comment: It did'nt work. Is there any way to do a one to one link between the contact_name of companies.model and name of contact.model.?